# Converting Vertex Attributes with igraph in R

Tags: r, igraph

I have been trying to convert to integer a vertex attribute I've created with the following command:

```
vertex_attr(net_frequency, "x") <- as.integer(10:14:13:10:19:9:13:14:21:11:17:14:11:9:11:7:17:9:9:8:13:15:19:9:1:8:12:3:9:16:10:5:5:4:10:3:10:14:3:3:10:4:3:6:10:14:6:12:16:13:10:3:13:6:15:9:7:4:1:6:3:3:1:12:11:15)
```

Though, when I try to check to be sure it was done properly, I get the following:

```
typeof(get.vertex.attribute(net_frequency,"x"))

[1] "character
```

Am I checking this wrongly? Converting wrongly?

Thank you very much for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible to convert the type of an attribute with igraph.

```r
> g<-make_graph(c(1,2))
> V(g)$foo <-  c('a', 'b')
> V(g)$foo <- c(1, 2)
> V(g)$foo
[1] "1" "2"
```

You will need to delete the attribute and re-create it with a different type. For example, to convert the above `c('1', '2')` to a numeric `c(1, 2)`, you could use the following:

```r
g <- g %>% delete_vertex_attr('foo') %>% set_vertex_attr('foo', value=as.numeric(V(g)$foo))
```